# Force Django ManifestStaticFilesStorage to always return urls with hashes

Tags: django, static-files

By default, `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` only returns urls with hashes in them when `DEBUG=False`. I want my development environment to be as close to production as possible, but I do need to set debug to False for a couple of things during development. Is there a way to tell `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` to always give me the url with hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ben432rew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669062/ben432rew)'s answer is close, but it's imperative that the `super` call of `url` passes `name` rather than `hashed_name`, unless you add some other code to the method that produces a variable with that name. Additionally, it's important that the last line of the your storage class's `url` return the value from its `super`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestStaticFilesStorage
from django.conf import settings


class BigBlindManifestStaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage):

    def url(self, name, force=True):
        """
        Override .url to use hashed url in development
        """
        return super(ManifestStaticFilesStorage, self).url(name, True)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could override the `url` method of `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` so that it always gives you the url with the hash.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestStaticFilesStorage
from django.conf import settings


class BigBlindManifestStaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage):

    def url(self, name, force=True):
        """
        Override .url to use hashed url in development
        """
        return super(ManifestStaticFilesStorage, self).url(name, True)
```

Comment: I like your class naming :).

Answer (score 1):

In Django ticket [#28847](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28847) a reason is given for `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`'s behaviour, but it does not account for setups where development is done not with the `runserver` command, but with a local webserver instance (e.g. Apache oder Nginx).
Thanks to ben432rew and Niko for their answers!